# Matlab: dividing a cell array into permutations of two column cell

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell

Assume I have this cell array:

```
in={'A' 'B' 'C'};
```

I would like to get possible `\t` separated permutations of `in` in two columns as:

```
out=
    'A' 'B     C'
    'B' 'A     C'
    'C' 'A     B'
    'A    B'  'C'
    'A    C'  'B'
    'B    C'  'A'
```

For a cell `in={'A' 'B' 'C' 'D'}` of length 4, there should be 14 different rows in `out` e.g., `'A    B' 'C    D'`. How to get `out` for any cell `in` of length `n`?

Please note that `A`, `B`, etc. are examples of input. The code is expected to handle strings in general. `'Alice02'   '_Tom'`, etc. can be examples of elements in input cell `in` instead of  `'A'  'B'`.

Comment: You're looking for [permutations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html), not combinations.

Comment: @beaker Yes, revised it. I need a specific format of output which comes in two columns and elements are separated by `\t`.

Comment: Can it be in 3 columns for the first case?

Comment: @emanbap well what I am looking for, should be only a two column output.

Comment: That would be a `6*2` cell for input of `3`, a `14*2` cell for input of `4`, a `30*2` cell for input of `5`, so on.

Comment: Can it be 'A ' ' B C    D' for a cell of length 4? The output can also be a cell?

Comment: @emanbap yes, `'A' 'B C D'` is one. `'B' 'A C D'` another, `'B C' 'A D'` is another, and so on. The output should also be a cell, yes, which each element appears as examples above in `' '`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The number of permutations is factorial(n). How does an input of size 4 give in 14 results? And in the size 3 case, what's the criterion to place the tab? For example, in the first of the 6 output rows, why is tab between B and C, and not betwen A and B?

Comment: @LuisMendo in the output, tab appears between two strings in the cell element whenever the element is supposed to contain more than one string. `B` and `C` in the first row are in the same column, so separated with `\t`, while `A` is in different column and is single element.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

```
str = {'John02' 'Alice_' '4_Tom'}
[x y]=find(dec2bin(0:2^numel(str)-1)=='1');
p = accumarray(x,y,[],@(z){sprintf('%s\t',str{z})});
out = [p(2:numel(p)/2) p(end-1:-1:numel(p)/2+1)];
```

If you are working only with letters you can use this:

```
str = 'ABCD';
[x y]=find(dec2bin(0:2^numel(str)-1)=='1');
p = accumarray(x,char(y+64),[],@(z){z.'});
out = [p(2:numel(p)/2) p(end-1:-1:numel(p)/2+1)];
```

Result:

```
out =
{
  [1,1] = D
  [2,1] = C
  [3,1] = CD
  [4,1] = B
  [5,1] = BD
  [6,1] = BC
  [7,1] = BCD
  [1,2] = ABC
  [2,2] = ABD
  [3,2] = AB
  [4,2] = ACD
  [5,2] = AC
  [6,2] = AD
  [7,2] = A
}
```

*Equivalent solution in Octave:

```
p = powerset('A':'D');
out = [p(2:numel(p)/2) ;p(end-1:-1:numel(p)/2+1)].';
```

Comment: `out` returns true values for `n/2` with `n` being the number of output rows. The other half would be the same - thou by exchanging the columns. But, can you please improve the code to get those spaces `\t` as a delimiter (as stated in the question description)? It should be able to handle words as the same as letters `A`-`D` with a tab delimiter in between.

Comment: This solution cannot handle "strings" as words of any type. For example when I replace the first line with `str = {'John02' 'Alice_' '4_Tom'}`it doesn't return permutations of these strings.